# Angular <mat-expansion-panel-header> does not expand

Tags: angular-material

I am learning Angular and using Material for Angular for styling.  For some reason the mat-accordian isn't working for me.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <h2>Post 1</h2>
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        <p>Post 1 Content</p>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <p>I'm in an expansion panel</p>

  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {
  MatInputModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatExpansionModule
} from '@angular/material/';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { PostCreateComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-create/post-list/post-list.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    PostListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatExpansionModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

[image]

I've tried reading other posts on stack overflow but nothing has seemed to work.
I tried installing with

```
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
```

but this doesn't work.  The accordion is just forever open.  Does anyone with Angular experience know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: If you install using the default installation and there are peer dependencies it will install an earlier version of Angular Material.

To Fix the issue I uninstalled Angular globally, cleared the cache, then reinstalled, and was able to resolve the dependency conflicts and install the latest version.